# Function for combining non blank cells with comma in between

Tags: vba, excel

```
Function COMBINE(rng As Range)
Dim cell As Range
Dim text As String
For Each cell In rng
Next cell
If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
Exit For
Else: text = text & cell.Value & ","
COMBINE = text
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Don't just dump a load of (unformatted) code - ask a proper question please. [ask]

Comment: `For Each...Next` loop will produce nothing as it is empty!

Comment: Your code as is won't compile. Had you formatted your code properly you would immediately see that you have an Exit For outside of the For loop. Also, your For Loop doesn't do anything.

Comment: I imagine your IF statement is meant to go inside the For loop, however, you would then be exiting at the first blank cell in the range so what happens if you have additional contiguous non-blank ranges after a blank cell in the supplied range?

Comment: ok, what should it be?

Comment: even if one cell is empty all following cells will be empty

Comment: from a1 to g1, only a1 b1 and c1 have b53 b54 and b55 resp. result should be 'b53, b54, b55'.. if a1 to f1 is filled they should be combined with a comma

Comment: Try putting the IF statement inside of the For loop for starters. And your return statement outside of the IF  i.e. COMBINE = text can be outside of the IF and the For loop.

Comment: Try to indent your code. It will really help you follow the flow, understand what you are coding, and perhaps understand better the suggestions you are being given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your function improved and well formatted:

```
Function COMBINE(rng As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim text As String
    For Each cell In rng

        If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            Exit For
        Else
            text = text & cell.Value & ","
        End if

    Next cell

    COMBINE = text

End Function
```